# Share method between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a `Func` like this:

```
int loopMax = 10, taskMax = 10;
int executionCounter = 0;

Func<int> calculator = new Func<int>(() =>
{
    executionCounter++;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (result + i >= int.MaxValue)
            result = 0;
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
});
```

Which could be called by multiple threads. For example like this:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[taskMax];
for (int i = 0; i < taskMax; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => _=calculator());
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I need to share the `calculator` function across all threads, and makes this function being called only once. In fact the `executionCounter` variable's value after running this code should remain 1, and all of the threads should have the same return value.

**UPDATE 1**

I think I can solve it if I find a way to server the first thread and block every other threads and after completion of first thread's method call, signal the methods result to other threads and also cancel them, to prevent them calling `calculator` again.

Using `lock` inside the method also is not what I am looking for, because in that case again the calculator is being called multiple times...

Comment: sooooo if i understand you correctly.. you want a bunch of threads executing the same function, but you _also_ want the function to be executed only once? that's logically impossible.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes exactly I want this

Comment: don't you see how "i want it executed by several threads" and "i want it executed only once" contradict?  having both is impossible.... it seems you are trying to solve a different problem you haven't realised yet. so: what are you actually trying to _achieve_ with this?

Comment: Maybe he confuses the word "once" with the word "simultaneously"?

Comment: @FranzGleichnann I thought about this, if it is possible to implement such a scenario or not....I thought about ReaderWriterLock, Semaphor, Producer-Consumer but could not find a way to solve it...

Comment: my core question right now: _why don't you calculate once and give the threads access to the result?_

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thats good question. Because I am intentionally, seeking a way to block other threads and call the calculate function and then signal the result to all blocked threads and prevent them from calling calculator method again.

Comment: be careful with this check:  `if (result + i >= int.MaxValue)`: this is somethint you never need to write, not in this way at least; `result + i`  is an `int`, so it will never be > `int.MaxValue`  (but possibly equal)

Comment: @GianPaolo yes you are right, it is just a sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class. This class provides support for lazy initialization. Here is how you could use it:

```
Lazy<int> lazyCalculator = new Lazy<int>(calculator);

Task[] tasks = new Task[taskMax];
for (int i = 0; i < taskMax; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => _ = lazyCalculator.Value);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

When a `Lazy` instance is constructed, it can take an optional [`LazyThreadSafetyMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode) argument. The default value of this argument is `ExecutionAndPublication`, with the behavior described below:

> Locks are used to ensure that only a single thread can initialize a `Lazy<T>` instance in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean and need.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want is that your `Calculator` method *can be executed by any thread, but this method should be executed only once*. If it is true, then we would use `lock` statement.

[The purpose of lock statement is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement):

> The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given
>   object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock

An example:

```
static object lockCalculatorMethod = new object();
static int executionCounter = 0;
static int loopMax = 10;
static int taskMax = 10;


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[taskMax];
    for (int i = 0; i < taskMax; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => _ = Calculator());
    }
    Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

and Calculator method:

```
static int Calculator()
{
    lock (lockCalculatorMethod)
    {
        if (executionCounter < 1)
        {
            executionCounter++;
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (result + i >= int.MaxValue)
                {
                    result = 0;
                    result += i;
                }
            }
            return result;
         }
         else
             return -1;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to cache result and avoid recalculation while calling by other threads, then you can [use threadSafe collection `ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8) and just get items from this collection:

```
static object lockCalculatorMethod = new object();
static ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

static int executionCounter = 0;
static int loopMax = 7;
static int taskMax = 7;


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[taskMax];
    for (int i = 0; i < taskMax; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var result = Calculator();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        });
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

And `Calculator` method:

```
static int Calculator()
{
    int result = 0;
    lock (lockCalculatorMethod)
    {
        int lockResult = 0;
        if (executionCounter < 1)
        {
            executionCounter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);                        
                lockResult += i;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(lockResult);
        }
    }
    queue.TryPeek(out result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, the method is being called multiple times again. I need it to being called only once  and share its result with every other threads...I

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to know for me to improve my answer! Thanks!

Comment: your solution is great, but again it will cause Calculator method to being called multiple times. See my update in question, I have tried to clarify it a bit more